# align-self: flex-end breaks on mobile zoom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a standard layout consisting of header, content and footer:

```
-----------------
|    header     |
|----------------
|               |
|    content    |
|               |
|---------------|
|---------------|
|    footer     |
-----------------
```

Everything works perfect on Desktop however if I use a mobile and zoom in on the footer it's no longer aligned to the end of the page:

```
---------------
|             |
|   content   |
|             |
|-------------|
|-------------|
|   footer    |
|-------------|
| empty space |
---------------
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#footer {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: `align-self` is for *cross-axis* alignment (for a column flexbox *cross axis* is horizontal) - you can use `margin-top: auto` on the `footer`... see https://jsfiddle.net/f5yuh7so/

Answer (score 3):

Consider using viewport height units.

In the body CSS, include: `min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: this seems to be working but my footer is now below my viewport on mobile. any idea why? anything less than 100vh brings back the issue.

Comment: It could have something to do with the mobile browser, they are tricky. Especially when the viewport gets resized on scroll.

What I usually do to solve footer related issues is a `div` which has `min-height: calc(100vh - $footer-height);`.

Comment: This works but if brings the original issue back. Anything less than 100vh breaks it.